# Observer carries beam of light and travels at speed of light

Tags: waves, particle-physics

I am more of an "arm-chair" quantum physicists, i.e. I'm interested in books and articles about the subject.

In the book "Tao of Physics" (Fritoj Capra) it mentions that when Einstein was 16, he tried to imagine how a beam of light would look to an observer who traveled along with it at the speed of light.

The book says Einstein concluded the observer would see the beam of light as an `electromagnetic field oscillating back and forth without moving`. Does this mean as a particle?

Intuitively I would think the light beam would look like a particle, rather than a wave because you and the light are travelling at same speed, but relative to each other, you are both standing at the same spot.

This part of the book made me stop and think.

Comment: You probably mean _beam of light_ and not [_bean of light_](http://i.ytimg.com/vi/N_utzLojCIE/0.jpg)?

Comment: Somehow 'bean of light' perhaps helps convey the wave/particle duality...  That aside, note this is more a special/general relativity question, not quantum.  Furthermore, you are entering a realm of physics where your intuition is very likely to be wrong and you will have to wrap your head around ideas that seem very odd the first few times you struggle with them.

Comment: @JonCuster of course, there are lots of interesting ideas with quantum physics .... hope study it at University eventually ....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, quantum/particle theory came later. What Einstein realized was that, travelling at the same speed as a light wave, the forward component of the fields "freeze", leaving only the lateral components able to vary. So the interplay between electric and magnetic fields which characterize electromagnetic radiation would be grossly affected.

All of this takes place within the framework of classical mechanics, and is superseded by the relativistic relationships which he later worked out.

Comment: That sounds fascinating. Not sure if I understand 100%, but I have some perception of what you are explaining (at this point I'm trying to get appreciation for quantum physics before I dive deeper) ...UPDATE Is this how the light would look to observer traveling at same speed http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electromagnetic_radiation#/media/File:EM_spectrum.svg

Comment: No, the point is that (classically) when you are travelling at the same speed as a light beam, it is Doppler-shifted to zero frequency. Look at http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electromagnetic_radiation, Properties. When you move along with the wave, its amplitude doesn't change.